# Hierarchy (Family Tree) Domain Model

Tags: functional-programming, f#

I'm wanting to model a family tree in the F# type system.  The basic requirements:

- A family tree is made up of `family members`
- A `family member` has a required `ancestor`
- A `family member` has an optional `partner`

My struggle is what to do with the "root" family member.  I thought about making it an `option`:

```
type FamilyMember = { Name:string; Ancestor:FamilyMember option; ... }
```

but it seems *all* family members are required to come from somewhere.

So, that lead me to think an `ancestor` union type, where either it is an empty `root` or it is a `descendant`.  Is there a cleaner way?

Here's what I have:

```
type Person = string
type FamilyMember = {
    Person: Person
    Partner: Person option
    Ancestor: Ancestor
}
and Ancestor = 
    | Root
    | Descendent of FamilyMember

let joe = { Person = "joe"; Partner = Some("joyce"); Ancestor = Root; }
let steve = { Person = "steve"; Partner = Some("pat"); Ancestor = Descendent(joe) }
let megan = { Person = "megan"; Partner = None; Ancestor = Descendent(steve)}
megan
```

Comment: An ancestor could be a parent's parent so better to use the word Parent instead of Ancestor and Child instead of Descendant.

Comment: A family tree is not a tree in the computer science sense of the word. It is (roughly) a directed acyclic graph, which cannot be stored as a simple record containing records. Hopefully that gives you something to look into.

Comment: Everyone has 2 parents :)

Comment: :)  Thanks for the feedback!  I'm interested in only modeling a single line of decent (paternal or maternal), so the second parent is simply a spouse.

Comment: I cross posted here, and got an interesting response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50842376/79113